# Why iterate by array with size faster

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, v8, jsperf

In first example I created empty array of length 1000:

```
var arr = new Array(1000);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  arr[i] = i;
```

In second example created empty array of length 0:

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  arr.push(i);
```

Testing in Chrome 41.0.2272.118 on OS X 10.10.3 and first block run faster. Why? Because JavaScript-engine knows about array size?

Benchmark is here http://jsperf.com/poerttest/2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify the array size it will have to keep allocating more space. But if you specify the size at the beginning, it only allocates once.

Comment: how does your theory explain http://jsperf.com/poerttest/6 ? wouldn't case 3 be faster than case 2 if re-allocation explained the performance differences? your theory makes sense, i'm just not sure it's true in V8.

Comment: @dandavis second and third example are the same, because the array size in the third example is 2000.

Comment: not only it needs to allocate more space - it also needs to copy contents every time it grows again and again. which turns `O(n)` algorithm into `O(n^2)` algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you allocate size, interpreter knows that it has allocate only 1000 element memory/space. So, when you insert element, it is just **one operation**. But when you declare dynamic array, 2nd scenario your case, interpreter has to increase size of the array and then push the element. It is **2 operations**!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could have been that `push()` is more expensive than assigning to a fixed position. But tests show it is not the case.

What happens is that empty arrays get a relatively small starting capacity (either hash pool or actual array), and increasing that pool is expensive. You can see that by trying with lower sizes: at 100 elements, the performance difference between `Array(100)` and `[]` disappears.